# Best way to handle android.os.RemoteException thrown by applyBatch

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, android-syncadapter, remoteexception

What is the best way to handle `android.os.RemoteException` thrown by `applyBatch()` method of `ContentResolver` or `ContentProviderClient`?

In my case I call `applyBatch()` of `ContentProviderClient` object passed in `onPerformSync()` method of `AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter`. Service corresponding to my sync adapter is defined with attribute `android:process=":sync"`.